# Validity of ARDL regression when there is I(2) variable

Tags: time-series, validity, ardl

I am trying to model relationship between Y(t) and Y(t-1), X(t), X(t-1) and Z(t) using ARDL model. Most cases these time-series are I(0) or I(1). However sometimes I encounter I(2) or higher order.

Question: are ARDL predictions still valid, although I know that F statistics is invalid when there is I(2) time-series.

Details:

- I am doing residual analysis for model to look for white noise (and more commonly stationarity and independence).
- Whether Y(t),X(t),Z(t) are stationare or co-integrate varies from case to case, as I have various different Y(t) time-series to be modeled.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding or ARDL is that every variable has to be integrated of the same order to use it. Are you saying that some of your variables are integrated of a different order?

Comment: I have mix of I(0), I(1) or even I(2) time-series sometimes when trying to model the Y(t).  

I found out that 
"The single equation approach by Pesaran et al. (2001) does not need to identify whether the regressors are I(0), I(1), or mutually cointegrated when finding a long-run level relationship among the dependent variable and the regressors. As discussed clearly by Pesaran et al.(2001), this is an advantage of their ARDL approach"
source: https://www.researchgate.net/post/I_want_to_know_if_we_can_apply_ARDL_model_in_case_our_dependent_variable_is_stationary

Comment: Also same source has comment "Yes as per pesaran paper...in order to apply Ardl....your dependent variable must be I(1)...independent variables can be mixture of I(0) or I(1)...However...it shld b checked that no variable should be I(2)...".

Comment: It does not make sense to me that the DV must be I(1) as you would prefer it to be I(0). Maybe they mean no more than I(1). In any case I think there is disagreement on this point. Some authors insist I believe that all variables be integrated of the same order.